# Nuka Carousel heightMode don't work in react

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I have a [nuka carousel](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel) with 3 slides and the height of the slides depends on the size of the content. So if one slide has 5 rows of text and another has 6 rows of text the one will be higher than the other.

So to fix this I found a [heightMode](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel/commit/f321e5f34629c27a791dfbc32f925fb60ed10ed0) prop where the slides height will be set after the tallest slide but when I test locally it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to change `slideHeight` manually?

Does anybody know if `heightMode` prop is working or not?

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered this problem and here's my fix. I Just added some css code:

```
.slider-list {
    height: auto!important;
}

.slider-slide {
    position: sticky!important;
}
```