# Nuka Carousel not displaying in react slideHeight props 0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, carousel, saleor

I am using nuka carousel in react TypeScript a saleor pwa react ts [app](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront)

Nuka carousel not showing items cause nuka is passing slideHeight `0` to `slider -frame`

 **Code Example:**

```
render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const { products } = this.state;
    const productsList = products.map((product: any) => (
      <Link to={'/product/' + product.id} key={product.id}>
          <ProductListItem product={product} />
      </Link>
    ))

    return (
      <div className="products">
        <div className="container">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
          <Carousel>
            {productsList}
          </Carousel>
        </div>
      </div >
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by just add  `if (products.length)` 

**Solution:**

```
render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const { products } = this.state;
    if (products.length) {
      const productsList = products.map((product: any) => (
        <Link
          to={'/product/' + product.id} key={product.id}
        >
          <ProductListItem product={product} />
        </Link>
      ))

      return (
        <div className="products">
          <div className="container">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <Carousel>
              {productsList}
            </Carousel>
          </div>
        </div >
      )
    }
    return null;
  }
```

> There is no need to override css this is proper way

Here is solution [Via Override css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468628/nuka-carousel-heightmode-dont-work-in-react). this is for those who is interested in css override